# Switching axis while generating histogram using data frames

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

```
index_size= 10
column_size = 1
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((index_size, column_size)))
df.columns = ['Value']
df.iat[0,0] = 5
df.iat[1,0] = 6
df.iat[5,0] = 8
df.hist(column='Value')
```

I get the below graph with 'Value' on X-axis and indices (0-9) on Y-axis but i want indices on X-axis and 'Value' on Y-axis.

[image]

I am expecting a graph like below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameter `orientation`, unfortunately it not in [`DataFrame.plot.hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html) documentation, because it contains last `kwds` parameter.

Parameter is possible find in [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

```
df.hist(column='Value', orientation="horizontal")
```

[image: graph]

EDIT:

Histogram plot counted values:

```
print (df['Value'].value_counts())
0.0    7
8.0    1
6.0    1
5.0    1
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

If need plot [`bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) or [`barh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html):

```
df.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

---

```
df.plot.barh()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thanks but how do i get it as a graph like how i have drawn?

Comment: I add it to answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Also, if there are multiple columns and i need to just plot 1 column. How do i do it? Setting (y=column name) did not work properly.

Comment: Use `df['colname'].plot.bar()` or `df['colname'].plot.barh()`.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to display with the way i was expecting.